# Completely Unload UIViewController in ARC iOS App

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm using the Facebook iOS SDK to have users authenticate and when they log out and log back in, the state of the main view controller, the one with the logout button, is in the same state as when they left it.

How can I completely remove the view controller from memory so that every time they log back in, the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method is called and the view controller is re-initialized.

Comment: `self.loginViewController = nil;`

Comment: Doesn't work, tried that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When done with it each time you need to release all references.

When you need to show it again, create and use a new instance. This is the only way to ensure `viewDidLoad` is called each time you need it.

Or if you want to keep reusing the same one over and over, add a `restart` method (or something similar). The implementation of this method can reset the UI to whatever starting state you need. Or you can put this logic in the `viewWillAppear:` method. This depends on whether `viewWillAppear:` can be called due to pushing and popping other view controllers.

Comment: Actually, setting the controller's `view` to `nil` should ensure `viewDidLoad` to be called next time `view` is accessed.

Comment: @Sulthan Good point. But I personally don't consider that the best way to reuse a view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't disagree but your answer was a bit incorrect.